# Pennies on Pay - Math Calculation - C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to double the amount of pennies for X amount of days.

So, 3 days = 4 pennies, 4 days = 8 pennies, etc

I'm stuck on getting the right code put in: (I know I'm close and I know I'm missing something silly. I've spent 5 hours on this. I just want to see the solution so my mind will put it together on how it works...)

I finally got it... now... how can I clean this up?? I'm still learning to write in less code... but I'm following the Starting Out w/ Visual C# book for now...

```
            // Local variables. /
            int daysWorkedInputValue;
            decimal currentPayRate, newPayRate, totalPaySalary;

            int daysWorked;
            int count = 0;
            currentPayRate = 0.01m;
            totalPaySalary = 0m;

            daysWorkedInputValue = int.Parse(daysWorkedInputTextBox.Text);

            if (int.TryParse(daysWorkedInputTextBox.Text, out daysWorked))
            {
                if (daysWorked >= 0)
                {
                    // Continue to process the input. /

                    if (daysWorkedInputValue == 0)
                    {
                        totalPayCalcLabel.Text = "$0.00";
                    }

                    if (daysWorkedInputValue == 1)
                    {
                        totalPayCalcLabel.Text = "$0.01";
                    }

                    // The following loop calculates the total pay. /
                    while (count <= (daysWorked - 1))
                    {
                        // Calculate the total pay amount. /
                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                            currentPayRate = 0.01m;
                            totalPayCalcLabel.Text = currentPayRate.ToString("c");
                        }

                        currentPayRate = currentPayRate * 2;
                        totalPaySalary = currentPayRate;

                        if (count >= 1)
                        {
                            totalPayCalcLabel.Text = totalPaySalary.ToString("c");
                        }

                        // Add one to the loop counter. /
                        count = count + 1;

                        // Return focus back to the organisms TextBox. /
                        daysWorkedInputTextBox.Focus();

                    }
```

Comment: Looks to be GP, Is it a Geometric Progression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)?

Comment: Please share the full code for the context of the question. you are not incrementing count and there is other stuff as well (no breaks, not reassignment of currentPay)

Answer (score 5):

I see a pretty obvious pattern here:

```
3 days -> 2^(3-1) = 4 pennies
4 days -> 2^(4-1) = 8 pennies
```

So you want to solve for the equation:

```
pennies = 2^(days-1)
```

I haven't run your code to see what's wrong (nothing's changing the value of `count` or `daysWorked` so I'm assuming you'll end up stuck in an infinite loop), but this should work just fine:

```
var pennies = Math.Pow(2, days - 1);
```